# How to develop with Hexo.io

Tags: hexo

I am using [Hexo.io](http://hexo.io) and like it so far but I am totally baffled by the workflow.

This is what I have to do - in one terminal I run `hexo server` so that I can see the local site. It insist on adding a hello world post (part of the core modules) and no way to get rid of it.

Then, in order for the site to show my changes I have to, in another terminal, run `hexo generate -w`.

Then before I deploy I actually need to run `hexo clean` before running `hexo deploy` or `hexo generate -d` as it seems that when it generates after changes it only changes the served site and not the generated site.

Completely and utterly baffling. Has anyone else experienced this? I am missing some trick?

Answer (score 5):

You just have to run `hexo s` to start server. If you edit/add a file(articles, layout, css, `theme/**/_config.yml`, etc..), Hexo detect it and regenerates automatically the new site. The only case where you need to stop and restart the server, is when you change the main `_config.yml` file.

`hexo generate` command is use to generate the blog one time.
`hexo clean` delete `db.json` file. Its useful when you have to delete useless tags and categories which are not linked to an article.
To deploy your blog, run `hexo clean`(optional) then `hexo generate --deploy`

Answer (score 1):

`server` command is there for you to preview your changes, it is by design to be non-persistent.

`generate` on the other hand create persistent HTMLs in the file system.

To `deploy`, HTMLs in the file system is required so either the deployer creates a temporary copy for you or you run `generate` before you deploy.